# Add active class to multiple tab navigation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using Twitter Bootstrap I'm trying to add a active class to both nav bars when a tab is clicked.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
   })
   $('#myTab2 a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
   })
</script>
```

Please see http://jsfiddle.net/dgQjA/ to get a better idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $(this).tab('show');
 var index = $(this).parent().index();
 $('#myTab2 a:eq('+index+')').tab('show');
})

$('#myTab2 a').click(function (e) {
 e.preventDefault()
 $(this).tab('show');
 var index = $(this).parent().index();
 $('#myTab a:eq('+index+')').tab('show');
})
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

You forget to add your code into `document.ready`

```
$(function(){
$('#myTab a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
$(this).tab('show')
});

$('#myTab2 a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault()
$(this).tab('show')
});
});
```